# Can't enable GCLK Generators for samr30-xplained (using RIOT OS)

Tags: timer, embedded, counter, atmel, riot-os

In simple terms:
    I am trying to setup a timer/counter clocked by an external source. The device is SAMR30-Xplained Pro and RIOT is the OS.

In a bit more detail:
    I am trying to get a gclk generator (e.g 6) to connect to a timer/counter (e.g TC4), and hooking up the generator to a GCLK_IO (PA22) as clock source. Only the generator 0 is active and makes the timers count, but other generators aren't even starting, even though I try to enable them. Here is my [code](https://github.com/Alturon/counting_external_source).

Would anyone know what is going on here? Is RIOT disabling them somehow?

Comment: Hi Naveed, it would be great if you could embed main parts of code to your question. It will increase your chance of getting good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

But could you check something in lines 38 and 42 of your external_event_counter.c? 

Shouldn't those busy waits be "while (GCLK->STATUS.reg & GCLK_STATUS_SYNCBUSY);" ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to configure the GCLKs manually.

Setting `.gclk_src` in the `timer_config` struct in `periph_conf.h` should be enough.
The GCLK is then enabled automatically by RIOT when you configure the timer.